# Why does my calculator concatenate instead of performing an operation?

Tags: javascript

```
    function add(a,b) {
        parseInt(a); // cross checking
        parseInt(b); // cross checking
        let result = a+b;
    getDis.textContent = result;
    }
    function sub(a,b) {
        parseInt(a); // cross checking
        parseInt(b); // cross checking
        let result = a-b;

        getDis.textContent = result;}
    function mul(a,b) {
     parseInt(a); // cross checking
        parseInt(b); // cross checking
        let result = a*b;
        getDis.textContent = result;}
    function div(a,b) {
        parseInt(a); // cross checking
        parseInt(b); // cross checking
        let result = a/b;
        getDis.textContent = result; }



    function operate(operator2,a,b) {
        if (operator2 == '+') { add(a,b)}
        if(operator2 == '-') {sub(a,b)}
        if(operator2 ==  '*') {mul(a,b)}
        if(operator2 =='/') {div(a,b)}
    } 




    // Populating the display


    let getDis = document.getElementById('display');

    let NUM = document.querySelectorAll('.n'); // select all the buttons with numbers
    NUM.forEach( (n) => {
        n.addEventListener('click', () => {
            getDis.textContent = getDis.textContent + '' + n.textContent;
        })
    })
    // clearing the calculator
    let CLEAR_ = document.getElementById('clear');
    CLEAR_.addEventListener('click' , () => {
        getDis.textContent = '';
    })

    // -----------------------------------------


    // OPERATORS

    let OPR = document.querySelectorAll('.operators'); // selecting all the operators except the equal operator
    OPR.forEach( (SIGN) => { // for each operators in the nodelist returned by OPR.
        SIGN.addEventListener('click', () => { // Upon clicking a operator save the first number(LHS operand) and flush the display.
            let SAVE_L = getDis.textContent;
            parseInt(SAVE_L); // parse it if its a string
            getDis.textContent = '';
            let SAVE_O = SIGN.textContent; // save the operator too for the operate() function
            let EQUAL = document.getElementById('equal');
            EQUAL.addEventListener('click' , ()=> {
                let SAVE_R = getDis.textContent; // when equal is clicked, save the RHS operand and flush the display.
                parseInt(SAVE_R); // parse it into a int if its a string
                getDis.textContent = '';
                operate(SAVE_O,SAVE_L,SAVE_R);})

        })

    })



    // ----------______---------------------------
```

I am trying to build a calculator from the odin projects project called calculator. i have almost wrapped up everything except just that the final result is concatenation instead of actual arithmetic operation. for example, 1+1 gives 11 instead of 2 and so on. how can i fix the problem in this code?

Comment: `let result = parseInt(a)+parseInt(b);`

Answer (score 1):

`parseInt(a);` doesn't modify `a`. You instead want `a = parseInt(a);`.

In general, except for a few exceptions (e.g. `array.prototype.sort`), a lot of the built in functions don't modify their parameters.